# Click a link, have a specific element clicked on next page

Tags: javascript, url, click, load, element

I want it so when you click a link to a page containing multiple filters, the next page loads, with one of the specific filters clicked. I tried the method of having the filter load when a specific url is showing, but it doesn't seem to execute the code. Thanks in advance!

```
window.location.href = "https://mare-island-brewing-co-vallejo.webflow.io/news?filter0=Category:%20Events";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
     document.querySelector('.filter-text-events').active = true;
     document.querySelector('.filter-text-events').click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`urlSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) on the `window.location.search` to return an object of the parameters in the url. Then run the constructor object through a loop and iterate over the event elements nodeLists.classList to see if there is a match. If the conditional is true run the `.click()` method on the element.

```js
// the elements affected by your event
const filters = document.querySelectorAll('.filters');
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // this string not needed if youa re getting the url using window.loaction.search
  const url = "https://mare-island-brewing-co-vallejo.webflow.io/news?filter0=Category:%20Events";
  // can replace url.split('?')[1] with => window.location.search
  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.split('?')[1]);
  // set an object and return the entries found in the parameters of the url
  const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
  // loop over the URL parameters
  for (let param in params) {
    // loop over the nodeList
    filters.forEach(el => {
      // check if the elements classList contains the parameter
      if (el.classList.contains(param)) {
        // for a click on the button
        el.click();
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Event Listener

```js
const selectEvent = (e) => {
  document.getElementById(e.target.id).classList.toggle('active')
}

filters.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', selectEvent));
```

So if for example you have an eventListener on the second page called selectEvent that toggles an active class, run a for loop over the URL search params object and then iterate over the event elements nodeList and check for a match on the parameter and the classList of the *event* element.

See the snippit for a working example using your URL string.

Let me know if this is not what you were look for and I can adjust or delete this answer.

```js
const filters = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-text-events');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // this string not needed if youa re getting the url using window.loaction.search
  const url = "https://mare-island-brewing-co-vallejo.webflow.io/news?filter0=Category:%20Events";
  // can replace url.split('?')[1] with => window.location.search
  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.split('?')[1]);
  // set an object and return the entries found in the parameters of the url
  const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
  // loop over the URL parameters
  for (let param in params) {
    // loop over the nodeList
    filters.forEach(el => {
      // check if the elements classList contains the parameter
      if (el.classList.contains(param)) {
        // for a click on the button
        console.log(el)
        el.click();
      }
    })
  }
})


// basic eventListner and callback function that may be set to show events when buttons are clicked
const selectEvent = (e) => {
  document.getElementById(e.target.id).classList.toggle('active')
}

filters.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', selectEvent));
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.filterBtn {
  width: fit-content;
}

.active {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: darkgreen;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div id="filter0" class="filter0 filter-text-events">This is the event that was selected on the first page</div>
  <div id="filter1" class="filter1 filter-text-events">This is the second event</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dale. I can't seem to still get it to work. I'll also say that just applying my original code gets the page to load with the filter pressed, but it's all the time and not just for that specific url. If you just visit /news, it's still pressed. So, is there a way to just have the url looked up before the code is executed?

Comment: Have you looked at the article by MDN I have linked to for the [URLSearchParams constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)? This constructor will give you an object of the key/value pair parameters sent over the URL.

Comment: Are you console logging the results of the object to see ifyou are indeed getting the parameters. Also have you added a corresponding **class** that ***matches*** the *key* of the parameter sent via the url to the **element** you wish to have your ***active*** state set to?

Comment: I'll check that article out. I don't really use Javascript too often, would I use console.log(.filter-text-events)

Also, I do have a corresponding class of .filter-text-events

Comment: Add your HTML code to your question and I'll see if I can specifically adjust my example to your code.

Comment: Here's what I have for the button link:

<a fs-cmsfilter-showquery="true" fs-cmsfilter-element="list" href="#" class="more-events_button w-inline-block">
                <div class="more-events_text hide">more events</div>
              </a>

Comment: From what I can read, shouldn't the filter query in the url just work? Other people seem to have success with that.

Comment: @JonDanyeur can you please add the HTML on the linked to page where your events section is residing to your question?

Comment: Hey Dale - here's that link: https://mare-island-brewing-co-vallejo.webflow.io/news

Sorry for the delayed response, we launched the site without the button for now.